# Third parameter in getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader()

Tags: android, android-loadermanager

hi i'm new here and also a beginner in android , i'm making a LoadManager called "contactsLoader" with callback in cursor

```
private LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> contactsLoader =
        new LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>() {
    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
        String[] projectionFields = new String[]{
                ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_URI
        };

        CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(MainActivity.this,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                projectionFields,
                null,
                null,
                null);
        return cursorLoader;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {

        adapter.swapCursor(data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        adapter.swapCursor(null);
    }
};
```

the problem is every time i called the function getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader()  in

```
private void loadingContacts() {
    Log.d(DEBUG,"We have permission to load the contacts");
    getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(CONTACT_LOADER_ID,new Bundle(),contactsLoader);
}
```

Appears to me this error:

```
Wrong 3rd argument "contactsLoader". Found: 'android.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<android.database.Cursor>', required: 'android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<java.lang.Object>'
```

I tried to understand what is wrong through those links [LoaderManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.html)
and [Loaders](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html) but i couldn't find the solution

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
getSupportLoaderManager()
```

You are calling the Support's `LoaderManager`.. From Support Classes... This way, you have to create proper `LoaderCallbacks` (from support SDK.. and not from android SDK)

So, open the file where you created `private LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks` and change this:

```
import android.app.LoaderManager;
```

To this:

```
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;
```